# Jenkins delivery pipeline plugin, how to skip manual trigger

Tags: jenkins

I have a setup with Jenkins build/delivery pipeline plugin where job #:

```
1) retrives code,
2) builds
3) runs unit tests
4) deploys to system test environment
5) deploys to UAT
6) deploys to Production
```

The deployments are manual triggers. Is it possible to somehow skip a manual trigger stage? Say, I would like to skip deployment to system test environment and deploy right ahead to UAT?  I could align all jobs 4-6 vertically on the same level so any builds between 4-6 can be built after 3, but it would still be nice to have these as a "chain". Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

It is fully possible to have the deployments happening automatically. In some cases you might want certain environments (e.g. dev) to be deployed with the latest version on every successful commit, while other environments (e.g. UAT, prod) might need to be manually triggered. This is possible with the current version of the Delivery Pipeline Plugin.

It's fully possible to make deployments happen simultaneously to different environments, but I think it makes more sense to start deploying to one environment, execute some smoke tests etc, making sure a certain set of assertions pass before going to the next stage. This avoids unnecessary work being executed and keeps the feedback loop as quick as possible.